# $_GET из формы

Tags: php, get

Всем привет.

Есть форма:

```
<form method="POST" action="action.php">
    <input type="text" name="action">
    <input type="submit" name="submit">
</form>
```

Нужно чтобы при клике на submit url становился вида: site.com?search=MySearch

Comment: интересно, зачем вам выставлять на показ все ваши переменные?

Comment: ghost rider, если это поиск, то что бы была возможность скинуть линку другу. обычный юзкейс.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

У вас способ передачи POST, попробуйте так:

```
<form method="GET" action="action.php">
    <input type="text" name="action">
    <input type="submit" name="submit">
</form>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
<form method="POST" action="action.php?search=MySearch">
    <input type="text" name="action">
    <input type="submit" name="submit">
</form>
```